# How to compare Two objects based of their keys?

Tags: javascript

I would like to compare 2 object using their keys. If the objects have the same keys, check their values. If the same save one instance of the pair in a new Object, otherwise save the pair whose value is 1 in the new Objects. 
Here is my attempt:

```
var sameKey = false;
function hasSameProps( obj1, obj2 ) {
  for (var x in obj1){
        if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(x)){ // check if the objects have same key 
          samekey = true;
        }
        if (sameKey){

        }
  }
}
var obj1 = {'a':0,'s':0};
var obj2 = {'a':0,'s':1};
hasSameProps( obj1, obj2 ); // should return new Object { 'a':0,'s':1};
```

Comment: Don't define a variable local to the scope of the function outside of it.

Comment: So the value you check is always '1' ?

Comment: Yes, the value to check for is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the logic inside the `if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(x))` like:

```
if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
   newObj[x] = obj1[x] > obj2[x] ? obj1[x] : obj2[x];
}
```

```js
var sameKey = false;

function hasSameProps(obj1, obj2) {
  var newObj = {}, samekey;
  for (var x in obj1) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
      newObj[x] = obj1[x] > obj2[x] ? obj1[x] : obj2[x];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
var obj1 = {
  'a': 0,
  's': 0
};
var obj2 = {
  'a': 0,
  's': 1
};
console.log(hasSameProps(obj1, obj2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function hasSameProps( obj1, obj2 ) {
  var returnValue = {};
  for (var x in obj1) {
        returnValue[x]  = obj1[x];
        if( obj2.hasOwnProperty(x)){ 
          if(obj2[x] == 1) {
            returnValue[x]  = obj2[x];
          }
        }
  }
  return returnValue;
}
var obj1={'a':0,'s':0};
var obj2={'a':0,'s':1};

var obj3  = hasSameProps( obj1, obj2 ); 
console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: fyi .. I only check from obj1 as a source. So if you have a key in obj2 that does not exists in obj1 , that key will not be included.

Comment: would I need to loop through the obj2 if I wanted  include its keys?

Answer (score 0):

So: both key and value the same, put in new object; key same, but not value, then put in new object with value 1?

```
var obj1 = { 'a': 0, 's': 0 };
var obj2 = { 'a': 0, 's': 1 };
var newObj = {};
for (var x in obj1) {
    if (obj2[x] && obj2[x] == obj1[x]) {
        newObj[x] = obj1[x];
    }
    else if (obj2[x] && obj2[x] !== obj1[x]){
        newObj[x] = 1;
    }
}
```